# Play chain futures

Tags: scala, playframework

i am developping some small web page on play for scala framework
and i use mongodb

member document has meberinfo include member id, and attendance document has

someone's attendance information.

so , i want to find members are in some group first , after then

find member's attendance information..

my code like below...

```
def attendanceBySubGroup(group: String, sub_group: String) = Action.async{

    var  obj : JsObject = Json.obj("group" -> group)
    if(sub_group ne "All"){
      obj = obj + ("sub_group" -> JsString(sub_group))
    }

    val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = member_list.find(obj).cursor[JsObject]

    // gather all the JsObjects in a list
    val futureMemberList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.collect[List]()




    val futurePersonsJsonArray: Future[JsArray] = futureMemberList.map {
      val m = ArrayBuffer.empty[JsObject]
      members => members.map{
        member => {
          val futureItem = attendance_list.find(Json.obj("member_id" -> member.\("_id").\("$oid"))).one[JsObject]
          futureItem.map {
            case Some(item) => member.+(("attendance" , item.\("attendance")))
            case None => member.++(Json.obj("attendance"-> false))
          }
        }
      }
      Json.arr(m.toList)
    }



    futurePersonsJsonArray.map {
      members =>
        Ok(members(0))
    }
```

but, it's not work that i want to

maybe, futureItem.map { .. is async call...

how can i return member list include attendance information..

thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to return all members in the inputted group/sub-group? I am getting thrown off by ```OK(members(0))``` . Are you using the Play-ReactiveMongo plugin? Do you have Play JSON Readers and Writers defined for your domain objects?

Comment: To chain futures use flatMap instead of map, or a for comprehension

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure , this is best solution...

but it is work correctly..

anybody find better solution..please post your answer

```
  def attendanceBySubGroup(group: String, sub_group: String) = Action.async{

    var  obj : JsObject = Json.obj("group" -> group)
    if(sub_group ne "All"){
      obj = obj + ("sub_group" -> JsString(sub_group))
    }

    val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = member_list.find(obj).cursor[JsObject]

    // gather all the JsObjects in a list
    val futureMemberList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.collect[List]()

    val futureMemberListWithAttendance = futureMemberList.map {
      members =>  members.map{
        member => {
           val futureItem = attendance_list.find(Json.obj("member_id" -> member.\("_id").\("$oid"))).one[JsObject]
           futureItem.map[JsObject] {
            case Some(item) => member.+(("attendance" , item.\("attendance")))
            case None => member.++(Json.obj("attendance"-> false))
          }
        }
      }
    }

    futureMemberListWithAttendance.map{
     val memberAttendances = ArrayBuffer.empty[JsObject]
     aa => Await.result(Future.reduce(aa)((s1, s2) => {memberAttendances+=s1; s1 } ) , Duration.Inf)
     Ok(Json.arr(memberAttendances))
   }
  }
```